# Power BI: percentage of multiple response question

Tags: powerbi

I presume this is really simple, but I cannot get my head around it. I was to show data the percentages from multiple response questions from a survey.

The original survey data looks like this:

[image: original data]

The variables starting with "Own:" are multiple responses, i.e. the first persons owns a car ("yes") and a donkey ("yes"), but no bicycle ("no").

I want to show the answers in Power BI in a chart like this, where I can the the percentage of respondents, who own a certain thing:
[image: chart]

I have already unpivoted the original data and it looks like this:

[image: unpivoted]

Now, I would like to create a measure that counts the number of "yes" per category. Is there any way to do a conditional count (count only "yes") - or transform all "yes" into 1 and "no" into 0 within Power BI?

If I had this measure, I could "simply" divide the number of mentions by the total number of respondents.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Best,
para

Comment: Please don't paste data as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this measure:

```
% Yes = 
VAR yes = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    'Table'[Value] = "yes"
)
VAR respondents = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID])
RETURN
    DIVIDE(yes, respondents)
```

[image]

Alternatively derive a numerical Yes column from Value

```
Yes = IF('Table'[Value] = "yes", 1, 0)
```

and then use

```
% Yes 2 = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Table'[Yes]),
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID])
)
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem or is something still missing?

Comment: Hi Peter - strange, I thanked you yesterday already for the amazing solution, which ignited a few light bulbs in me! No more questions-an amazingly concise answer!! Best -para